# String resources data holder

Tags: java, android, string

I would like to use string resources but I don't know how to implement it. Here is the related code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textNazov.setText("Company name: "+ zaznamy.get(position).get(DataModel.TABULKA_NAZOV));
    holder.textCislo.setText("Number: "+zaznamy.get(position).get(DataModel.TABULKA_CISLO));
    holder.textEmail.setText("E-mail: "+zaznamy.get(position).get(DataModel.TABULKA_EMAIL));
    holder.textAdresa.setText("Adress: "+zaznamy.get(position).get(DataModel.TABULKA_ADRESA));
    holder.textMesto.setText("City: "+zaznamy.get(position).get(DataModel.TABULKA_MESTO));
}
```

How to implement @string  here ?

```
<string name="compName">Company name</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access string.xml from java code, you can do it like this :

```
getString(R.string.compName);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get like

```
String compName = getResources().getString(R.string.compName);
```